# Convert Colon Separated String to a PowerShell Dictionary

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to convert Colon Separated String to a PowerShell Dictionary. Following are the strings.

```
$inputkeyvalues = "Appsetting:true|environment:prod"
```

I have two key value pairs's in the `$inputkeyvalues` variable and those are separated by pipe delimiter. 
first one is: Appsetting:true
second one is: environment:prod

and I'm trying to convert to PowerShell dictionary. The final output should be something like,

```
Key            Value
-----         -----
Appsetting     true
environment    prod

$Dictionary= New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
```

Can someone please suggest me possible solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `hashtable`:

```
$inputkeyvalues = "Appsetting:true|environment:prod"

# Create hashtable
$Dictionary = @{}
# Split input string into pairs
$inputkeyvalues.Split('|') |ForEach-Object {
    # Split each pair into key and value
    $key,$value = $_.Split(':')
    # Populate $Dictionary
    $Dictionary[$key] = $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  I stripped the @{ and } characters of the string then created the dictionary key value pairs.     

   $totalDict=@{}
   Foreach ($itemDictString in $tempObj.tag_instances)
   {
        $Dictionary=@{}
        $itemDictString.Replace('@{','').Replace('}','').Split(';') | ForEach-Object{
            $key,$value=$_.Split('=').Trim()
            $Dictionary[$key]=$value
        }
        $key="tag_id"
        $composite_key="$($tempObj.first_name) $($tempObj.last_name) $($tempObj.id) $($Dictionary[$key])"
        Write-Host $composite_key

        if($totalDict.ContainsKey($composite_key) -eq $true)
        {
            $totalDict[$composite_key]=$totalDict[$composite_key]+1
        }
        else
        {
            $totalDict.Add($composite_key,1)
        }
   }
```